# Can't find mount point (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, mount

On our Ubuntu 10.04 server, I've configured it to automount a 2nd hard drive to `/mnt/wd15/` but now I can't unmount (using umount) it or find the entry in `/etc/fstab`.

How do I unmount it (or/and find out how its mounted)?

Details:

I get the following error messages:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
umount: /dev/sdb1: not mounted

sudo umount /mnt/wd15/
umount: /mnt/wd15/: not mounted
```

This is my `mount` output (same as /etc/mtab):

```
# sudo mount

/dev/mapper/veda-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs type debugfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

Comment: @Zoredache: Is that the same as /etc/mtab, I don't see it there, unless its included in /dev/mapperr/hostname-root ?

Comment: So, how did you configure this to mount automatically at boot?  The fact that you're not seeing it in /etc/fstab means it's probably not even trying.

Comment: Oh, now I feel dumb, I forgot about the possibility that it's never been mounted and that its just using the primary drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what devices are mounted to what directories using "mount"...

```
mount
```

It will list the device first, then the mount point, then the file system type, and finally, mount options.